# Add parameters in result array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm using Code Igniter,I try to add $finalamount to the result_array.

```
   $this->db->select('customer_id, customer_ref, i_points, group_points, created_on');

    $run_q = $this->db->get('employees');   

 if($run_q->num_rows() > 0){

        foreach ($run_q->result_array() as $get) {
            $totalpoints = $get['i_points'] + $get['group_points'];

            $percent = 17;

            $amountbycustomer = $totalpoints * 26 * $percent;

            $amountbypref = $this->final($get['customer_id'],$percent);

            $finalamount = $amountbycustomer + $amountbypref;

            $get['finalamount'] = $finalamount;
        }
        return $run_q->result_array();

    }
```

**But in my view, this error**

```
<td class="employeeCustomer"><?=$get['customer_id']?></td>
<td class="employeeCustomerRef"><?=$get['customer_ref']?></td>    
<td class="employeeAmount"><?=$get['finalamount']?></td>//line 65
```

Message: Undefined index: finalamount

Filename: employees/employeeslist.php

Line Number: 65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning just the result array from the db and not actually adding the final amount to the individual rows. You have to do something like this:

```
public function stmt() {
    $this->db->select('customer_id, customer_ref, i_points, group_points, created_on');
    $run_q = $this->db->get('employees');
    if ($run_q->num_rows() > 0) {
        $rows = $run_q->result_array();
        foreach ($rows as $k => $get) {
            $totalpoints = $get['i_points'] + $get['group_points'];
            $percent = 17;
            $amountbycustomer = $totalpoints * 26 * $percent;
            $amountbypref = $this->final($get['customer_id'], $percent);
            $finalamount = $amountbycustomer + $amountbypref;
            $rows[$k]['finalamount'] = $finalamount;
        }
        return $rows;
    }
    return false;
}
```

OR using pass by reference (notice: `&get`):

```
$rows = $run_q->result_array();
    foreach ($run_q->result_array() as &$get) {
        $totalpoints = $get['i_points'] + $get['group_points'];

        $percent = 17;

        $amountbycustomer = $totalpoints * 26 * $percent;

        $amountbypref = $this->final($get['customer_id'], $percent);

        $finalamount = $amountbycustomer + $amountbypref;

        $get['finalamount'] = $finalamount;
    }
    return $rows;
```